# Proof by Contrapositive help?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble providing a proof by contrapositive here, can anyone provide a proper proof by contrapositive here?

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $3x+1$ is even if and only if $5x-2$ is odd.

Comment: Hint: The contrapositive of P implies Q is NOT Q implies NOT P. As this is an "if and only if" you must break this into two separate implications.

Comment: Hint: $\,3x+1\,$ is even *iff* $\,x\,$ is odd.

Comment: Hmm thank you Sean. My struggle here was whether or not to separate into two implications or not. Simple mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We shall prove that $3x + 1$ is even iff $5x - 2$ is odd by means of contraposition.

(Necessity, i.e., $5x - 2$ is odd implies $3x+1$ is even) Suppose $3x+1$ is odd, i.e., of the form $2j + 1$ for some integer $j$. Then $3x = 2j$. Now write

\begin{align*}
5x - 2 &= 2x + 3x - 2 \\
&= 2x + 2j - 2 \\
&= 2(x + j - 1)
\end{align*}

and so $5x - 2$ is even, whence the desired result by contraposition.

(Sufficiency, i.e., $3x + 1$ even implies $5x - 2$ odd) Suppose $5x - 2$ is odd, i.e., of the form $2k + 1$ for some integer $k$. Now, employing a similar technique from above,

\begin{align*}
3x + 1 &= 5x - 2x + 1 - 3 \\
&= 5x - 2 - 2x \\
&= 2k + 1 - 2x \\
&= 2(k - x) + 1
\end{align*}

and so $3x + 1$ is odd, whence the desired result by contraposition. $\square$

**Remark.** Note that as we are discussing even and odd numbers, $x$ must necessarily be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use *congruences* mod. $2\,$: you want to prove that 
$$ x+1\equiv 0\mod 2\iff x\equiv 1 \mod 2, $$
and the contrapositive is
\begin{align}&&x\not\equiv 1\mod 2 &\iff x+1\not\equiv 0\mod 2,\\
&\text{i.e. } \qquad &x\equiv 0 \mod 2&\iff x+1\equiv 1\mod 2, \end{align}
which is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Proof:
if $5x-2$ is even then $3x+1$ is odd

$5x-2$ is even $\implies 5x-2 = 2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\implies 5x=2(k+1) \implies 5x$ is even $\implies x$ is even

Then, $x = 2s$ for some $s \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\implies 3(2s) +1 = 6s+1 = 2(3s)+1$ is odd

Similarly, you can prove that if $3x+1$ is odd then $5x-2$ is even

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $3x+1$ is even and $5x-2$ is also even, then $3x+1 = 5x-2 - [2(x-1)-1] = \text{even} - \text{odd}= \text{odd}$ , contradiction. On the other hand....assume $5x-2$ is odd and if $3x+1$ is odd, then $2x-3 = (5x-2) - (3x+1) = \text{even} - \text{even} = \text{even}$, contradiction to the fact that $2x-3 = 2(x-1)-1$ is clearly ..odd.

Comment: This is a proof by contradiction. The problem with a proof by contrapositive for me is that the first half of the proof assumes not q, which would be that 2x-5 is even, which would mean that it is a factor of 2k for some k in the integers, and it is not, which is a difficulty for me in the proof.